# Excel VBA: Disable Auto Open when Save As function is run

Tags: excel, vba, save-as

I am running a code that takes the data that is input and creates a copy of the file. That is fine; however, the new file opens every time it is saved. I would like to save the file without it opening up automatically. I was playing around with some code, listed below:

```
 Dim x As Object
        Set x = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
        x.Remove VBComponent:=x.Item("TestModule")
```

Below is the entirety of the code for the Save As function.

```
Public sourceWB As Workbook
Public sourceWS As Worksheet
Public targetWB As Workbook
Public targetWS As Worksheet
Public sDate As String

Sub Main()

   sDate = Format(Now(), "mm.dd.yyyy")
    Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Sheets("**FILE NAME DISCREET")


    Set targetWB = Workbooks.Add
    Dim theFilename As String
   theFilename = "**FILE NAME DISCREET**" + sDate + ".xlsx"

   targetWB.SaveAs FileName:= **"FILE LOCATION TO BE KEPT DISCREET, SORRY "**
    Set targetWS = targetWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

   sourceWS.Range("A1:H45").Copy targetWS.Range("A1")
   targetWB.Save

End Sub

Private Sub ManhExportData_Click()
       Call Main
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought that the workbook could be opened again every time it is saved because it is **already** open, and Excel won't allow you to have the same workbook open twice in the same instance of Excel.  Or are you just asking how to close the workbook after you save it (i.e. `targetWB.Close`)?

Comment: I am creating a new workbook when I save it. Each week I am inputting numbers into a spreadsheet and when I click "Save As" I am creating a copy of the current spreadsheet so I have a record of what I do each week. Then I just continue to edit the current workbook each week. So, when I press Save As, it opens up the new workbook each time.

Comment: Your current code (1) performs a `Workbooks.Add` to create a new, empty, workbook, meaning you now have two workbooks open; (2) performs a `Save As` on the new workbook to commit it to disk; (3) copies a range from your old workbook to the new workbook; (4) performs a `Save` on the new workbook to commit the changes to disk; (5) stops.  You are left with the two workbooks open - the original one and the one you `Add`ed, but at no stage has the "saving" opened a workbook.  Do you just want to know how to close the new workbook?

Comment: That would be very helpful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to close the workbook you created with the `Add` method, you should use a `Close` method on the workbook.

```
Public sourceWB As Workbook
Public sourceWS As Worksheet
Public targetWB As Workbook
Public targetWS As Worksheet
Public sDate As String

Sub Main()

    sDate = Format(Now(), "mm.dd.yyyy")
    Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Sheets("**FILE NAME DISCREET")

    Set targetWB = Workbooks.Add
    Dim theFilename As String
    theFilename = "**FILE NAME DISCREET**" + sDate + ".xlsx"

    targetWB.SaveAs FileName:= **"FILE LOCATION TO BE KEPT DISCREET, SORRY "**
    Set targetWS = targetWB.Sheets("Sheet1")

    sourceWS.Range("A1:H45").Copy targetWS.Range("A1")
    targetWB.Save

    'Close the workbook
    targetWB.Close

End Sub

Private Sub ManhExportData_Click()
    Call Main
End Sub
```